# couchdb document design for edges in a directed and wieghted graph with timestamps

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm struggling a bit with the "best" design for storing "graph-ish" data in couchdb/pouchdb.
I have movements/traffic of a specific amount at a specific time between nodes I want to store, so it's a bit like a directed and weighted graph with timestamps.

Each piece of data has:

- a timestamp
- an amount
- a source
- a target

The questions I have, and that I want to answer with this data, are:

- what are the last X movements?
- what movements take place in a specific timeframe?
- what is the in- and output of node N (in a specific timeframe)?
- what is the in- and output in the set of nodes N, N1, .. (in a specific timeframe)?

So, how to store the data in couchdb, that I can answer the questions and make use of the most of couchdbs power-features and specialities?

From my current point of view, I have two choices: store everything but the amount in the _id, or build the _id only with the timestamp, and use extra values for amount, source and traget.

For the first solution, view functions could be build like [here](http://docs.ehealthafrica.org/couchdb-best-practices/#n-to-n-relations), and the document could look like this:

```
{
"_id":    "app:movement:at:20150517T154200:from:node:aaaa:to:node:bbbb",
"amount":  123456
},
```

for the second solution, documents could look like this:

```
{
"_id":    "app:movement:at:20150517T154200", # maybe plus random value
"from":   "aaaa",
"to":     "bbbb",
"amount":  123456
}
```

view-functions will not use regexs like in the first example, but have direct access to the values.

What is more "chouchdb-ish"? What would you do? what is more future-proof?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to define the `_id` values as UUID. Your solution has advantages in one single use-case: when you want to use the primary index `_all_docs` to request the data e.g. for performance reasons. But it will limit the use-cases for your data handling a lot.

An example doc structure could be

```
{
  "_id":    "", // UUID
  "from":   "",
  "to":     "",
  "amount":  ,
  "timestamp": "", // ISO8601
  "type": "movement"
}
```

Now you want to request the data:

> what are the last X movements?

With a view with `doc.timestamp` as key you can ask

```
_view/viewname?descending=true&limit=3
```

to get the last 3 movements.

> what movements take place in a specific timeframe?

With a view with `doc.timestamp` as key you can ask

```
_view/viewname?startkey=:timestamp1&endkey=:timestamp
```

to get the movements in that timeframe.

> what is the in- and output of node N (in a specific timeframe)?

It works the same in the timestamp handling but you will need a view with a complex key. Your view can emit par example:

```
emit([doc.from,doc.timestamp], null)
emit([doc.to,doc.timestamp], null)
```

Now you can prepend the node to the timeframe filtered requests.

> what is the in- and output in the set of nodes N, N1, .. (in a specific timeframe)?

Its the same as the use case before. But to request multiple nodes data in one request is possible only when the node names are located in index side-by-side. Otherwise you will need multiple requests to the CouchDB.